# Show that there is a $c\in(0,1)$ such that $c^n f(c)=\int_0^c x^n f(x)dx$ if $\int_0^1 x^n (1-x) f(x)dx=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $$\int_0^1 x^n (1-x) f(x)dx=0$$ Show that there is a $c\in(0,1)$ such that $$c^n f(c)=\int_0^c x^n f(x)dx.$$ where $n$ is a non-negative integer.

Special case:$n=0$

If $\int_0^1  (1-x) f(x)dx=0$ so  there is a $c\in(0,1)$ such that $$f(c)=\int_0^c  f(x)dx$$
that solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3627804/show-that-there-is-a-c-in0-1-such-that-fc-int-0cfxdx).

Special case:$n=1$

If $\int_0^1 x (1-x) f(x)dx=0$ so  there is a $c\in(0,1)$ such that $$cf(c)=\int_0^c  xf(x)dx.$$

Proof:

Define the function $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, such that

$$g(x)=x\int_0^x t^n f(t)dt-\int_0^x t^{n+1}f(t)dt, \forall x\in[0,1].$$

So

$$g'(x)=\int_0^x t^n f(t)dt+x^{n+1}f(x)-x^{n+1}f(x)=\int_0^x t^n f(t)dt, \forall x\in[0,1].$$

Observe that $g(0)=g(1)=0$. Hence by Rolle's Theorem  $\exists b\in(0,1)$, such that $g'(b)=0$, that is,

$$\int_0^b t^n f(t)dt=0.$$

Now define $h:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, such that $$h(x)=e^{-x}g'(x), 
\forall x\in[0,1].$$

Now $h'(x)=-e^{-x}g'(x)+g''(x)e^{-x}=e^{-x}(g''(x)-g'(x)), \forall x\in[0,1].$

Observe that $h(0)=h(b)=0$. Hence by Rolle's Theorem  $\exists c\in(0,b)\subseteq (0,1)$, such that $h'(c)=0$. So $$e^{-c}(g''(c)-g'(c))=0\\\implies g''(c)-g'(c)=0\hspace{0.3 cm} \\\implies c^nf(c)=\int_0^c x^nf(x)dx.$$

Is this calculation valid?
(Also the solution here is almost identical to the solution in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3627804/show-that-there-is-a-c-in0-1-such-that-fc-int-0cfxdx), but more general)

Comment: *“First, is this calculation valid?”* Yes, I think so. Is there a “second” part in your question?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, your solution here is identical to the solution in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3627804/42969 applied to $\tilde f(x) = xf(x)$.

Comment: Why did you have to redo all of that? Just let $F(x) =x^nf(x) $ and apply linked proof to $F$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh , Thanks for the point